# How to find the references of an Interface function which is used in multiple projects? (Project count > 500)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2015

I am having a interface function called say "WriteOutput". which is implemented by OutputLibrary.dll.

This dll is being referred in multiple projects, say more than 500. How can I find the references of WriteOutput.

Comment: Easy way... Change it and see build errors! :)

Comment: use grep/find ?

Comment: Right-click... **Find all references**.  I'm assuming the 500 projects are all in the same solution

Comment: Emad, But I have to build all the projects. My application is huge.

Comment: MickyD no of projects is more around 600

Comment: Find All references will only check in a solution. MickyD

Comment: If they are not in the same solution, the only way i think is using a Grep tool, as @BugFinder has told you

Comment: You can use a tool like nDepend

Comment: Thanks MickyD. I have written a batch file to build all the assemblies. then I have injected a build error. As Emad told. thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

After reviewing individual comments, according to me, you may write a small program which will reflect all referenced assemblies in any given assembly. You can place all of your assemblies to be inspected in a folder and let you logic to iterate over individual assembly to find referenced assemblies. This approach at will let you filter assemblies those consume your Interface.

```
Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoadFrom(filename).GetReferencedAssemblies()  //HERE FILENAME IS YOUR ASSEMBLY TO INSPECT
```

[Find sample here](http://shazwazza.com/post/how-to-inspect-assemblies-before-including-them-in-your-application-with-reflection/)